# How to generate all possible combinations from list elements in Python having Pandas DataFrames in list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

Good afternoon!
I have a list of lists in Python. Example:

```
mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
          [1, 2],
          [df1, df2]]
```

`df1, df2` are Pandas DataFrames. I want to generate result similar to `itertools.product(*mylist)`.

The problem is that Pandas DataFrames are iterables themselves, so the result which `product` returns is not what I want. I want:

```
[('a', 1, df1),
 ('a', 1, df2),
 ('a', 2, df1),
 ('a', 2, df2),
 ('b', 1, df1),
 ('b', 1, df2),
 ('b', 2, df1),
 ('b', 2, df2),
 ('c', 1, df1),
 ('c', 1, df2),
 ('c', 2, df1),
 ('c', 2, df2)]
```

But `product`, of course, can not generate the desired ouptut, since it begins to iterate over `df1` and `df2` columns. How can I solve this problem in an elegant and Pythonic way?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure? `product()` iterates over the iterables passed to, it but only one level deep.

```py
>>> from itertools import product
>>> mylist = [[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], [[4, 6], [8, 9]]]
>>> for x in product(*mylist):
...     print(x)
(1, 'a', [4, 6])
(1, 'a', [8, 9])
(1, 'b', [4, 6])
(1, 'b', [8, 9])
(2, 'a', [4, 6])
(2, 'a', [8, 9])
(2, 'b', [4, 6])
(2, 'b', [8, 9])
```

See? That `[4, 6]` and `[8, 9]` are themselves iterables is irrelevant to `product()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I found the mistake in my code in another place.